# How many years did Lister survive after coming out of stasis?

Tags: novel, red-dwarf

According to the Grant Naylor ***Red Dwarf books*** *Infinity Welcomes Careful Drivers* and *Better than life,* how long did Dave Lister survive once Holly brought him out of stasis?

> I mean, before he un-dies at the end of the second book

I'm looking for a novel related answer. The TV show, while funny, has followed a different storyline.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the book does say

> the crew planned to go back to him in 36 years, which I assume is the time needed for him to age backwards to how old he was when it all began. And he was 61 years old when he had the heart attack, so that would fit if he was 25 years old when it started.

Comment: Somehow I knew you'd be the one to answer first! ;)

Comment: Finally, my account name pays off.